# SvelteKit supabaseUrl is required - after successful deployment

Tags: sveltekit, supabase

I keep getting this error after I deploy my app with `npm run preview` and when I deploy through Vercel. I get no error when the app is "building"

The problem isn't the .env variables being used in Vercel's environment as it successfully builds.

The problem is somewhere in my code as it also happens in localhost when previewing.

`npm run dev` works fine.

I have also rebuilt my app as well - meaning I started a new sveltekit project, reinstalled supabase and set everything up from scratch and still no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is you are importing the env variables from `$env/dynamic/public` but this should be from `$env/static/public`. We currently have this mistake in some of our docs that we will rectify.